# Confused by ASP.NET Identity and IdentityDbContext

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity, asp.net-identity-2

It's been a while since I've done any serious work using ASP.NET authentication and I'm a bit rusty. Especially now that ASP.NET Identity is the in thing. I'm hoping I can explain what I'm doing and have someone tell me why and where my assumptions are wrong or if they're not wrong.

The application I'm building is going to be HIPAA compliant, and as such I cannot store any personally identifiable information in the database. So I spent some time looking at how ASP.NET Identity works, noting things like my *ApplicationUser* (which inherits from *IdentityUser*), as well as the *ApplicationDbContext* (inheriting from *IdentityDbContext*). I read a couple MSDN articles and so forth.

I then noticed that *IdentityDbContext* seems to be tied to the *AspNetUsers* table in the database. I then noticed something concerning for me in the *AspNetUsers* table since I'm writing an application which cannot store anything personally identifiable: Email and PhoneNumber columns.

So I wanted to remove those. I looked under the hood a bit and saw that the *AspNetUsers* table is mapped to the *DbSet* property of *IdentityDbContext* (see [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn497626(v=vs.108).aspx)). *TUser* is *ApplicationUser*, which inherits from *IdentityUser*. And *IdentityUser* has Email (see [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.aspnet.identity.entityframework.identityuser_properties%28v=vs.108%29.aspx)).

So...after all of that...my question is this: if I want to create my own version of *AspNetUsers* WITHOUT phone number / email address / etc. I will have to create my own implementation of IUser in place of IdentityUser, correct?

Are there any particular gotchyas I'm going to run into doing this, then, or should this be a fairly straightforward task? Am I going to gut a lot of pre-written code by just wanting to remove Email from the database?

Personally, to me, it seems unreasonable that the Email property is part of any fundamental class associated with user identity -- especially when ASP.NET Identity is being touted as something highly flexible (it would seem more reasonable to me to just have people add their own Email property to the auto-generated *ApplicationUser* class).

It may seem silly for me to worry so much about a column I could just write anything into, but for anyone who has ever had to deal with HIPAA regulations it can strike paranoia into your heart (and want to do everything you can to remove anything which could even be mistaken as holding onto personal information).

Comment: Create your own `IUser` entity and don't bother with the fields you don't want.  Asp.Net Identity is made to be extensible like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Getting rid of a phone number should not be a problem. Removing Email field would be a bigger pain, as it is used by the framework.

I'd implement my own `IUserStore` (and all related) classes. Look on this post for initial guidance: http://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2014/01/20/implementing-asp-net-identity.aspx

Then get [Identity source code](https://aspnetidentity.codeplex.com/) with their `UserStore` and gut out all the bits that require email to be present.